# angular2 Select binding when options collection changes

Tags: html, angular

I am using angular2 and have an HTML select like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="myList" [(ngModel)]="mySelectedItem">
    <option value="">{{ "ALL" }}</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of allItems" [value]="item">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

For examples sake let myList= ["option1", "option2", "option3"]

This all works fine until the allItems collection is changed. When the user is first presented with the page, they select "option1" as their preferred option. Now the javascript modifies the allItems collection and removes "option1" as a valid option. At his point the Select shows nothing.

What I would like to happen is that the Select shows the first option "ALL" if the value is of the Select is not a known value in the AllItems collection.

The value of the myList collection are changing automatically based on some other logic in the javascript.

Can someone advise how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you show some of your ts/js?

Comment: You should clean the `mySelectedItem` object when the `allItems` array changes, or at least first check if `mySelectedItem` is inside the `allItems` array.

Comment: I can try the clean option, but was concerned that by changing mySelectedItem in the (ngModelChange) event of the Select I would cause a kind of infinite loop. But I'll give it a go anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try below,

```
 import { Component }  from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: `<h3 class="title">Basic Angular 2</h3>
   <hr />
   <select class="form-control" id="myList" [(ngModel)]="mySelectedItem">
    <option value="all">{{ "ALL" }}</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of allItems" [value]="item">{{item}}</option>
   </select>
   <button (click)="updateLIst()" >Update</button>
  `
 })
 export class AppComponent {
   mySelectedItem= 'all'
   allItems  = ["option1", "option2", "option3"];
   constructor(){}

   updateLIst(){
     this.allItems  = [ "option2", "option3"];
     this.mySelectedItem = 'all';
   }
 }
```

wherever allItems changes set `mySelectedItem` to `all` in your java script code.

Here is the [Plunker!!](https://plnkr.co/edit/B0qV8DImwGQBAGbPHvc4?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!